# Deleting Item from BindingSource Leaves Blank Row in DataGridView Which it is Connected to as DataSource

Tags: c#, winforms

I am working on a winforms project where I have a bindingsource connected to a DataGridView.  Adding and updating work like a charm, but when I remove an item, it leaves a blank row.  Any item added after this, is added after the blank row.  I tried refreshing the DataGridView, set AllowUserToAddRows to False, and a few other suggestions I found on StackOverflow.  Any help would be appreciated to solve this issue.  Thanks.

Here is the code I have so far.

```
// Setting the binding source
IList<Contact> contacts = getContacts();
contactBindingSource.DataSource = contacts;

// removing the item
var currentContact = (Contact)dataGridView1.CurrentRow.DataBoundItem;
contactBindingSource.Remove(currentContact);
```

Comment: The posted code works.  Might have to give us more information.

Comment: @LarsTech It does remove the row from the Datagrid that works, but it leaves a blank row in its place.  If I add a new contact to my bindingsource it adds the new row in the datagrid after that blank row.  Now, if you mean that you are not getting the blank row, then I will take a closer look at my code.  Thanks.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm saying.  Using the code you posted, the row disappears in my grid.  It's not going blank.  Try recreating the issue in a new project.

Comment: @LarsTech, ok will do

Comment: Starting with a new project it works.  The only difference is that I am getting the contact to add from another form as a POCO.  Love it when this happens, Thanks for at least looking at this.  Back to the drawing board.

Answer (score 0):

you can first remove item from gridview then remove from data source

```
 int x = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index;
 dataGridView1.Rows.Remove(DataGridView1.Rows[x]); 
 contactBindingSource.DataSource = dataGridView1.DataSource as DataTable;
```